# Rails 3.1.2: Set association without saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to set an association on an activerecord object without having that association be persisted, so that what I've just set it to is returned when I invoke the association method. Is there a nice way of doing that?

Example:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :foos
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :bar
end

this_bar = Bar.find(1)
this_foo = Foo.find(1)

this_bar.foos = [this_foo] # This performs a save, which I don't want
this_bar.foos #=> should return [this_foo]
# further computation #
```

(What I'm trying to achieve is allow the user to see a "preview" of what the object will look like after update, but still give the option to cancel out the update.)

Comment: Are you sure this_bar.foos = [this_foo] is performing a save...as in being saved to the DB? That does not look right at first pass. Dbl check and be sure it is indeed being saved. Prove it to use by doing it in the console and showing us the output. ;)